# how to fetch data from webservice in REACT useEffect function and send it to props object?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-props, use-effect

I'm trying to fetch data from a webservice to a child component. It looks like Data are fetched ok in console.log() inside useEffect function. I'm not able to work with them in higher function scope. I'd like to access fetched data in the child component (PComponent) through the props object.

Thank you for any advice.

```
function App(props) {
  let data = undefined;

  useEffect( () => {
    console.log('UseEffect');
    const  fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(someUrl)
      data = result.data;             
      console.log('result',data);
      return data;
      
    };
    data = fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <PComponent settings = {data}/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `useState` hook to store your data. Any state update will rerender the component and therefore data is passed to the child.

```
const App = (props) => {
   const [data, setData] = React.useState()
        
   const fetchData = async() => {
      const result = await axios.get(someUrl)
      setData(result);           
   };
        
   // Fetch data when component mounted
   useEffect( () => {
      fetchData()
   }, []);
          
   return (
      <PComponent settings={data}/>
   );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes i know, but i'd like to send data through props only? it is possible? Because if use setState and also props data are in both state and props. it is ok?

Comment: Your data flows from the parent to the child. The single source of truth is the state in your parent component, so its ok to distribute your data among as many child components as you like. If data changes all child components will get the updated data.

Comment: I understand but these data are not changing at all.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter if its changing or not. If it doesn't change your component won't rerender and neither the childs. Using useState here is the absolute right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `useState` for state which can change in functional components. You can read about that [on the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

```
function App(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(async () => {
    console.log("useEffect running");
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(someUrl);
      console.log(result.data);
      return result.data;
    };
    setData(await fetchData());
  }, []);

  return <PComponent settings={data} />;
}
```

Comment: Do i have to? it is not possible send it directly to props?

Comment: @J.Rautner It may be possible to do `<PComponent settings={(await axios.get(someUrl)).data} />` but I haven't tried it and I don't think that would work